# How to handle different roles for multiple elements for a single user?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, jwt

First of all, I'm new to spring-boot and spring-security.
I've read a lot of documentations (especially on http://www.spring.io) but I don't find a lot of information. I'm also working with JsonWebTokens, so all my authentication process is based on this. I followed this excellent tutorial to implement JsonWebToken authentication with spring-security : http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-2-stateless-authentication/

So here is my problem :
I am working on a bug tracking application. For each project, multiples users may have different role (reporter, developer, admin, etc.). In the aforementioned tutorial, the authority is grant for the whole restful API, and the user only have one role for the entire API. However, in my case, I need to check first if the user has the good role for the good project (project is sent through http query parameter) and I have no clue how to handle this. To summarize, a user could call an URI like `/tickets/close/{id}` on a project, but not on another.

At the moment, my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter overrides the configure() method like :

```
http
...
.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
.anyRequest().hasAuthority("ROLE_USER").and()
...
```

But it obviously don't take care of the query parameter in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after is not "different roles" for a user, rather authorizing a user for access to an object or set of objects.

Read through [Domain ACLs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/domain-acls.html), your users would be authorized differently for different projects, and the project would be the parent authorizing object for the issues, and issues would inherit from projects.

Answer (score 0):

Since your security rules needs to consider your application domain, I would implement the security rules within your controllers. If your controllers detect that a user is trying to access a forbidden resources, you would respond by an ResponseEntity with a 503 error.

What I usually do is to throw a custom exception from my controller and define an Exception Handler. That exception handler would handle the 503 response. Here is an exemple :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerConfig {
  @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<Error> handleInvalidFileFormatException(HttpServletRequest request, RuntimeException ex) {
    Error error = new Error(0, new Date(), request.getRemoteAddr(), request.getRemoteHost(),
    request.getHeader("User-Agent"), ex.getMessage(), ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(ex));

    if (ex instanceof ValidationException) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Error>(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    LOGGER.error("Error while processing request.", ex);

    return new ResponseEntity<Error>(errorService.save(error), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
  }
}
```

This is a custom ValidationException handler that generates a 500 HTTP response  with the error message wrapped in a JSON object. You would reuse that for yourself with a custom SecurityException and flag the ResponseEntity with a 503 rather than a 500.

Best of luck.

Edit : ACL would definately be the best choice to keep the proper segregate of your business logic from the security aspect. However it might be complicated to setup if you are not familiar with Spring Security Advanced concepts.